# Search in .csv file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, search, csv

I have an .csv file with round about 10.000 Lines. 
Now I have a textfield in which the User typing a value than he Click on a Button. 
Now this value should be searching in the .csv and then in this Linie all values should be Displayed in a Label

E.g.

.csv:

PLZ, Name, Code                                         47158, Neuss, DE005116                            46356, Moers, DE006151

ViewControler:

Textfield search: 47158
Label1: Neuss
Label2: DE005116

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 google search would have made you happy ;)

http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data

**EDIT** To answer your question below.

```
while ([scanner scanFloat:&myVariable] && [scanner scanFloat:&myVariable2] && [scanner scanFloat:&myVariable3]) {
   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myVariable], @"theKeyInTheCSV",
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myVariable2], @"theKeyInTheCSV2",
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myVariable3], @"theKeyInTheCSV3",
                nil]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) but One question. In The First example in the Homepage he Said it is with two clolums but I have 6 and such as i can say label1 = clolum 2 ?

Comment: Just the example has two columns, should be a problem with the parser.

Comment: Ok how can i add 4 more columns? And who can i say label1= colum2 in The founded line?

Comment: Updated the answer. You get the values by entering the attributes name

Comment: Thanks :) just One more question. How can I set "myVariable" = Label1. Also that wenn I Start The search Button, that The value of "myVariable" Displayed in Lable1 and The value of"myVariable2" in Lable2 and so on

Comment: You have to make an IBOutlet to a NSTextField and set textField.stringValue = myVariable;
This is really basic stuff you should know before actually starting a huge project ;) You'll find tons of tutorials on the internet

Comment: One more question to The Code from The Website. Who typing in The Name from The .csv file and who typing I in The Name auf the textfild with The search  value ?

Comment: What do you mean? readFromURL:ofType:error: is the method executed when opening a file. I really can't help you with all of this. Check out the basics of Cocoa first.

Comment: So I try to use the Code from the homepage, but the Code opens the Csv file from am URL but my one is local also I'am trying this:  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Zollämter Access" of Type@"csv"]; NSString +mytext = [NSString string WithContentsOfFIle:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];   But it does not work :( Can you help me with this? It is very importent! ANd how can I set the search value is the mytext (ALso the textfiled on the viewcontroller?)

Comment: Have you checked with NSLog if the string was loaded?

Comment: No, iam very new in xcode, but this project must be ready this eavenig and the only thing that is missing in the "serach VIewController", also the searching in the csv an display the resaut in label's I hope you will help me

Comment: I will, just answer my questions above ;)

Comment: ok thanks for the video but this is for mac I need this for iPhone and wenn I will use NSTextFiled is is doesen't exists

Comment: So check with NSLog ;)
You will see if your Text-File gets loaded, you can delete it afterwards. 

Doesn't matter, this is IBOutlet in general. Seriously, don't panic and actually watch the stuff. You just make an outlet for UILabel instead

Comment: I have a Textfiled on the ViewController.xib and 10 Labels and one "Ok" button, now the ueser typing in an serach value in the text field and thann the resault must be displayed in the 10 Label's for each cloums in the csv file one Lable

Comment: Then you make 10 IBOutlets for your labels, and you insert the results with [self.propertyNameLabel setText:theStringValue];
I guess we're soon going to have the record of the most comments ;)

Comment: OK thanks :) also e.g. IBOutlet NSString *Name; in the .h and than in .m [self.Name setText:NameZ]; ? Ok and what should the IBAction for the "search Button" look like?

Comment: No, your property would look like the following

Comment: @property (assign) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName;

Comment: And then you connect it to the label, watch the video, it shows the process

Comment: ok: .h = @property (assign) IBOutlet UILabel *Zollamtsnummer; and than connect to the label = done and now in the .m synthesize ? and what is with the IBAction for the searach Button?

Comment: With Objective-c 3.0 you don't need to synthesize anymore. If you get a warning in the .m file, you still have to do it. For the IBAction just do

Comment: - (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;

Comment: it works :) but who I get the search result in the label in who looks the -(IBAction)serach_Button:(id)sender; ?

Comment: So how must the IBAction for the search Button looks like, that the entired value must be search in the csv file? this is the last "big" problem of the project. I hope you will help :)

Comment: I hope you will help me with this problem :) To write the IBAction for the search button, so it will search for the value which is typing in in the textfield. :)

Comment: you get the string of the file, then you search with the parser, put the found string in variables, and set the labels. All of this I have answered above at least once ;)

Comment: ok thanks bu in the code above (from the website) he open the csv from an server but my is local in the app whit the name "Zollämter Access" can you give me one example wite only one variable then I do the other self.

Comment: I just do not get it :( can you give me an example with one variable? and taht die csv is not on an server, it is local Name: "Zollämter Access"

Comment: I did, above. In the IBAction do NSLog(@"%@", [NSString string WithContentsOfFIle:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]); and tell me what you get

Comment: I write an answere so you can see my problem

Answer (score 0):

her is my code:

```
-(IBAction)Zollamtsname:(id)sender{


    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Zollämter Access" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]);
    if ( nil == mytext ) return NO;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myText];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:
     [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n, "]];
    NSMutableArray *newPoints = [NSMutableArray array];
    float test1, test2;
    while ( [scanner scanFloat:&test1] && [scanner scanFloat:&test2] ) {
        [newPoints addObject:
         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:test1], @"test1",
          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:test2], @"test2",
          nil]];
    }
    [self setPoints:newPoints];
    return YES;
}




//[self.Zollamzsnummer setText:@"test"];
```

}

i get 4 errors and I don't know how so solve them :( 1."return NO" = the void method should not return a value
2. "return YES" = the void method should not return a value
3. [self setPoints:newPoints]; = Not visible @interface for'ViewController_suche'declares the selector setPoints

ANd who I say that the serach value is in the textfield?

Comment: Oh my dear Nils. Why didn't you start your research earlier?
Why would you return anything to a void method? Just remove the return YES; and return NO; statements. setPoints-method does not exists. It was an example. You have to decide what to do with the data yourself.
This is fetched data. You have an array with all of your data.
If would be optimal if you made a class, like 'Product'.
Then you can filter it with NSPredicate

Comment: This is pretty complex for beginners, I'm sorry if I can't help you like this.

Comment: Ok than i remove the return YES an NO and the setPoint. Is this enough? is then re resault in the variable test1 and test2? And what did you mean with research?